# partial derivative substitution in differential equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-derivative

$$y''+(y'+2y)y'+2y^2=0 \tag{*}$$ 
1.when $ u=y^2 $ express $\frac{du}{dx}$,$\frac{d^2 u}{dx^2}$ in terms of $y,y',y''$ 
2.when satisfy initial condition $y(0)=1$, $y'(0)=1$ , find solution for differential equation in * above , but $0 \le x \le \frac{\pi}{2 \sqrt 3}$

attempt: 
1. I wasn't sure about the substitution. it is said $u=y^2$  
is the relation u -> y ->x? 
 
$\frac{du}{dx}=2y \frac{dy}{dx}$

$\frac{d^2 u}{dx^2}=$$\frac{d}{dx}(2y \frac{dy}{dx})$ 
$\frac{d^2 u}{dx^2}=$$2(\frac{dy}{dx})^2+(2y \frac{d^2y}{dx})$

$\frac{d^2 u}{dx^2}=2(y')^2+2yy''$ 
is this right?

2. number two I wasn't sure enough should I express $y''$ & $y'$ in u? 
   $\frac{u''-2(y')^2}{2y}=y''$ using what is known above,
   I tried but I got $\frac{u''}{2}-\frac{(u')^2}{2u}+u'+2u=0$
   I'm sure I'm close to right here

Answer (score 0):

substituting $$u(y)=y'(x)$$ then we get
$$y^2(2u(y)^2+(yu'(y)+2)u(y)+2)=0$$
this can be written in the form
$$\frac{du(y)}{dy}=-\frac{2\left(\frac{1}{u(y)}+u(y)+1\right)}{y}$$
can you solve this equation?
the solution should be $$y(x)=c_2 e^{\frac{1}{2} \left(\log \left(\cos
   \left(\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{3} \left(2
   x-c_1\right)\right)\right)-x\right)}$$

Comment: thanks but did my attempt wrong? is  $u(y)=y'(x)$ same as $\frac{du}{dx}=2y \frac{dy}{dx}$ ? and how can I get $y^2(2u(y)^2+(yu'(y)+2)u(y)+2)=0$ ?  I mean there is no $u''$?

Comment: i tried i got $y=Ae^-2x+Be^-2x.x$, if i look closely using $u'=2yy'$ & $u''=2yy''+2y'$, i can change the problem to $\frac{u''}{2}+u'+2u=0$

Comment: ah sorry wrong calculation, i got $y=e^{-u}(Acos \sqrt 3 u+B sin \sqrt 3 u)$!!

Comment: ok is your problem solved now?